# The feet of the perpendiculars from the vertices of a parallelogram to its diagonals are vertices of a parallelogram

Tags: geometry

> Prove that the feet of the perpendiculars drawn from the vertices of a parallelogram on to its diagonals are the vertices of a parallelogram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obvious. If the given parallelogram is centered at ${\bf 0}$, and $\pm{\bf a}$, $\>\pm{\bf b}$ are its vertices, then the four constructed points are $\pm\lambda {\bf a}$ and $\pm\mu{\bf b}$ with certain $\lambda>0$, $\mu>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider two points on a diagonal corresponding to the opposite vertices of the smaller quadrilateral. By rotational symmetry, the distance between one point and the vertex closer is equal to the distance between the other point and the vertex closer to it. Since diagonals bisect each other, we will then get that distance between the $2$ points on the diagonal are equidistant from the center. Now construct your quadrilateral, and observe that the quadrilateral is divided into $4$ triangles. By SAS congruence criterion, we will get that opposite triangles are congruent. This implies that opposite sides of quadrilateral are equal, which means it is a parallelogram.